# Why do some motorbikes need consistent throttle/acceleration/raise to keep the engine alive even if i have pressed full clutch?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, rpm, pulsar, apache

I am used to riding Pulsar 150, when I press full clutch in that, the engine is still alive without the need of throttle/acceleration/raise to keep the minimum rpm. But I was riding a TVS Apache RTR 200 recently and when I wanted to stop the bike, I pressed full clutch to stop but the engine died after around a second. Is it required by design to give throttle/acceleration/raise to maintain minimum rpm or does the bike have problems.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure, but it sounds like the bike has a problem. It should be able to idle without throttling.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, are you saying with the clutch disengaged, in other words you are squeezing the clutch all the way in the engine is stalling? Is this happening after you start, or it's heated up? Is it as you are rolling to a stop?

Comment: @GdD When the clutch is fully disengaged or when i press the clutch lever in hand fully. So generally bikes have idle rpm around 1500 rpm. But the bike requires acceleration/throttle to keep the rpm up and engine running. So is that the bike designed this way to be cool because it requires consistent revs or is it in efficient to maitain idling rpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your engine requires throttle to keep it from stalling in neutral or with the clutch disengaged then there's a problem. There's nothing cool or desirable about having to keep throttle on to prevent your engine from quitting on you, it could leave you without power when you really need it, so you should get it resolved. There are many things it could be, but one easy thing you could look at is the idle adjustment. There's a screw at the end of the throttle cable, you screw it in to increase the idle speed, and out to reduce it. I'd try screwing it in to see if that helps.